# How to add object collision to this wall?

Tags: javascript, object

I made this code: https://code.sololearn.com/W3i7v2LuHhoB but I can't get the object collision to work. I searched on a lot of forums, YouTube, etc and still can't find it.

```
var rightArrow = 0;

function leftArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
  if (rightArrow === 0)
    var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
}

function upArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
}

function downArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image1");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
}

function moveSelection(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 39:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 38:
      upArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 40:
      downArrowPressed();
      break;
  }
};
```

I don't get any errors.

Comment: What have you tried for the collision code? Is the black rectangle element what you are trying to test collision against with your gif character?

Comment: Yes! i tried to make a map with like 1,01,1 for the places but i didnt get it too work for this code, also i cant find anything that would help me with it.. besides already made code wich im just not able to pick out of it and implement it in my code already.. Im really trying hard to find something but yeah its getting frustrating so thats why im asking here! cause im sure someone here would know how to do it..

Comment: *"cant get the object collision to work"*: there is nothing in your code that looks like an attempt to detect a collision.